# what to do when i am not sure about correct Stack Exchange community to ask questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am having doubt about asking questions. I see there are different stack exchange communities. If i'm not sure about the correct community to ask questions, what should i do?

Is it okay if i ask question in community in which i think it will be okay. 
Also i'm not sure any community where i can ask question. Is there any general/all questions community?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) is the site for questions about the entire Stack Exchange network. It has a [[site-recommendation]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag designed specifically to help you find the right home for your question. You can post there if you're in doubt and you'd rather not risk getting your question closed.